# CPU spike high in postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, cpu, postgresql-9.6

We upgraded postgresql from 9.3 to 9.6 and we found that after upgrading postgresql consumes overall 75% of CPU.
We are having web based application(JBOSS) which will communicate to postgresql 9.6 
We are having performance measures scripts which will call rest API and run for 1 hour and collect the overall CPU utilization.

Overall CPU utilization after 1 hour is around 75% with the below configuration.

**postgresql.conf:**

max_worker_processes=16

max_parallel_workers_per_gather=8

force_parallel_mode=on

shared_buffers=3GB

maintenance_work_mem=1GB

backend_flush_after=1MB

bgwriter_flush_after=1MB

bgwriter_delay=10ms

min_wal_size = 1GB

max_wal_size = 2GB

synchronous_commit=off

effective_io_concurrency = 100

max_prepared_transactions=1000

**Hardware Configuration**

CPU = 8 Core

Memory = 16GB

**postgresql data dir resides in NFS.**

These performance spikes were not faced in postgresql 9.3(Overall CPU consumption is around 50%)

Can any one help on this?

Comment: Did you do "ANALYZE" of entire database after the upgrade?  
You enabled parallel query support - this can cause more CPU utilization. It's not bad - queries are using more CPU but results are returned faster.

Comment: We ran VACCUM  after upgrade. Even if I disable force_parallel_mode=off still I am getting cpu above 75%.

Comment: One more thing, I just set  huge_page=on, shared_buffer=300MB in postgresql.conf and  number of huge pages  in my system is 166(sysctl  vm.nr_hugepages). With this change my CPU comes down to 45 to 50 % but response time got increased.

Comment: VACUUM (reclaim space used by old row versions) and ANALYZE (compute column statistics) are two separate maintenance procedures. Did you do an ANALYZE? I think the statistics are lost on upgrade.

Comment: I ran ANALYZE for entire database but it does not help.

Comment: I ran strace command one of the child pid of postgress and I am seeing lot of lseek system call. Is it right? lseek(92, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 13770752
lseek(92, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 13770752
lseek(92, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 13770752
lseek(92, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 13770752
lseek(92, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 13770752
lseek(92, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 13770752
lseek(92, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 13770752
lseek(92, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 13770752
lseek(92, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 13770752

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm seeing something very similar after upgrading from 9.5 to 9.6 and am pulling my hair out.